# Selenium test: re-authenticating with BasicAuth gives an error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm writing tests for SeleniumRC in Python. The tests run against a Firefox instance in Ubuntu. I've got a webapplication that uses BasicAuth.

In the setup of my testclass I set up a page (foo.html) in my webapplication.

I've got a lot of tests in this class that go to this page and authenticate themselves using a URL like:

```
self.selenium.open('http://user:pass@%s:%s/foo.html' % (host, port))
```

I've got one test (let's call it BAR) that creates another page (bar.html) and then opens that page:

```
self.selenium.open('http://user:pass@%s:%s/bar.html' % (host, port))
```

And here's the center of my problem:

- If I run just this one test (BAR) the login works.
- If I run another test before this one that does BasicAuth and goes to another URL (like foo.html, which is common in my case) I get a BasicAuth screen.

If I change the call for opening bar.html and have:

```
self.selenium.open('bar.html')
```

- If I run just this one test (BAR) the login fails (I get a BasicAuth screen)
- If I run another test before this one that does BasicAuth and goes to another URL I can succesfully go to the URL.

So the problem basically is: I can't *always* do a BasicAuth because then the BAR test will fail most of the time. Never doing a BasicAuth is also not an option because I can't count on the BAR test coming after another testing doing a BasicAuth.

The problem seems to look like the one described [here in the SeleniumRC docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#permission-denied-error), but I can't figure out why this re-authenticating should give an error in this case...

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox.
Try changing the following flag by typing in url `about:config` and search for below filter:

```
browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled
```

[image]

You can change the state of this flag in the default Firefox profile using about:config service page (double click on the flag to change it's state) From now on the Firefox should let you go through http authentication using name and password in the url. (Note that if you are using Selenium WebDriver 2.6 or higher this flag should be disabled by default)